# What is this light fixture type? I have never seen it anywhere before. (North America)

Tags: light-fixture, led, bathroom-fixtures, light-bulb

A couple of these lights went out in my bathroom. Brought the light-bulb to HomeDepot where staffs there also couldn't identify it. No other markings found except for the "Type T Shielded" shown in the picture.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that you cannot put in a halogen bulb back in right now. The previous owner removed the glass shield over the bulb and it must be found and reinstalled or replaced. The glass shield is necessary to absorb UV light given off by the bulb, to protect against injury from glass during a bulb explosion, and to reduce the risk of fire from objects contacting the bulb.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Newhouse-Lighting-75-Watt-Equivalent-T3-LED-Bulb-Halogen-Replacement-Light-Bulb-Double-Ended-RSC-Base-Non-Dimmable-Soft-White-4-Pack-T3-5075-4/304815927

Comment: @user71659 Halogen bulbs do not give off significant amounts of UV. You're thinking of fluorescent tubes, I think?

Comment: @Hearth No, halogen lamps [emit enough UV](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2829662/) to be a hazard. The glass [is a UV shield](https://www.tampabay.com/archive/1992/05/03/most-halogen-bulbs-have-shielding/).

Comment: Fluorescent tubes should be fine, but they're harder to find nowadays. Everything has LED replacements nowadays.

Answer (score 11):

The fixture type is quite common. The bulb in it now is not. That's a LED replacement (perhaps not a good one if it died - certainly crude and likely early) for a halogen bulb. Something like a T3 R7s 78mm (the mm is the length end to end  there are a few options. 118mm is another.)

There are T3s that are not double-ended. The original bulb looks like this, more  or less. You can still get them. Don't get more than 100W if going that route.

[image] *image source https://5fc98fa113f6897cea53-06dfa63be377ed632ae798753ae0fb3f.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/product_images/files/000/025/381/legacy_product_detail_large/53746_eaca83989f5aa21ad003c5241674b7fdb426396d_original.jpg?1429822457 no endorsement implied.*

Newer LED replacements are less crude, perhaps.

[image] *Image source https://www.superbrightleds.com/media/catalog/product/cache/cb26e5a64f935c0ec4578d3774ebd133/r/7/r7s-27k8w-store.jpg no endorsement implied*